# How to delete a record from table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a problem with deleting a record from my SQLite3 database:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('databaza.db')
c = conn.cursor()
data3 = str(input('Please enter name: '))
mydata = c.execute('DELETE FROM Zoznam WHERE Name=?', (data3,))
conn.commit()
c.close
```

Everything is OK, no errors, but the delete function doesn't work!

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: what exactly is not working? which version of python are you using?

Comment: Great, so what does *delete doesn't work* actually mean?

Answer (score -8, accepted):

Thank you to everybody who tried to help. The right code is:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('databaza.db')
c = conn.cursor()
conn.text_factory = str    
data3 = str(input('Please enter name: '))
query = "DELETE FROM Zoznam WHERE Name = '%s';" % data3.strip()
print(query)
mydata = c.execute(query)
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection!

Answer (score 17):

The correct syntax for a [parameterized](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) query is:

```
mydata = c.execute("DELETE FROM Zoznam WHERE Name=?", (data3,))
```

Make sure the parameter uses the comma, to make it a python tuple.

This will help prevent SQL Injection which is possible when passing in a formatted string. More on SQL Injection [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15972508/referring-to-a-python-variable-in-sqlite3-delete-statement).

Comment: there is a typo with the last character in the string. The bracket should be removed. I can't edit it as edits need to be 6 characters apparently.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little late to the party but if you Google search "python sqlite delete row" This is the first thing that comes up and I was having the same issue where things were not getting DELETE'd from my sqlite DB.
I'm using Python 2.7 on Debian Jessie.

Previously, when I wrote Python code for adding and retrieving information in the sqlite database, I had written the commands with correct capitalization where needed and it worked.

```
curs.execute("SELECT example_column1 FROM example_table WHERE example_column2=(?)", (Variable,))
```

However...

```
curs.execute("DELETE FROM example_table WHERE example_column1=(?)", (Variable,)):
```

This for some reason does not work with the DELETE command. I had to send that command in all lower-case before sqlite would respect the command being sent.

```
conn=sqlite3.connect('example.db')
curs=conn.cursor()
curs.execute("delete from example_table where example_column=(?)", (Variable,))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

I have no idea why. 
I tried all the previously mentioned methods but having the command sent in lowercase was the only way I could get it to work.
Hope this helps any struggling neophytes in their journey into Python and sqlite.

Comment: What makes this work is the 'commit' to the DB, not the lowercase comand.

Comment: Hello from the future.
To clarify, I already had commits.
The final block was to specifically show commits are being used.
I never figured out why this happened but changing DELETE to delete fixed my problem.
It was the only thing I changed since I isolated the code to its own .py to do troubleshooting. Changing it in my main code and in the troubleshooting code yielded the same results.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
mydata = c.execute('DELETE FROM Zoznam WHERE Name = (?)', (data3))
```

Without the ',' and the '?' between '()'

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Python 3.9 on windows.

```
c.execute("DELETE FROM Zoznam WHERE Name={0}".format(data3))
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score -2):

I advise you to first make a string for the query , and then execute it. ex:

```
query = "delete from zoznam where name = '%s' " % data3
c.execute(query)
conn.commit()
```

Comment: seriously, where do ye get such ideas?

Comment: I don't know why , but I had many problems trying to execute  queries in sqlite enclosing the actual string query as the first argument of the execute method, but somehow I could solve this problem creating a variable out of the string and then pass it to the execute method.

Comment: As noted in the above answer, *always* use the parameterized version of the sqlite commands instead of creating query strings by hand. This will prevent (or at least greatly reduce the risk) for SQL injections.

Answer (score -3):

Check the file permissions.

An aside, I prefer the tokenized method:

```
mydata = c.execute("DELETE FROM Zoznam WHERE Name='%s'" % data3)
```

Comment: Please enter name: ... `';DROP TABLE Zoznam;` <Enter>

Comment: You clean all input prior to running it through the cursor.  It's no different than what's already there.

Comment: also, name whose I ask not erase from SQL