# Referring to a python variable in SQLite3 DELETE statement

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, where-clause

I am writing a function to delete a record from a table. The variable I am trying to refer to in the delete statement is a Tkinter entry field.

I get the variable using the .get() method, but I can't then pass this into the SQLite statment without returning an error.

The following code is part of the frame, I've only added the relevant code to the problem

```
from tkinter import *

import sqlite3

class EditOrdersForm(Frame):

        def __init__(self):

        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("Edit Orders form:")
        self.pack()

        def displayDelOrderOptions(self):
            self.deleteOrderOptionsLabel = Label(self, text="Enter the Order ID of the order you wish to delete: ").grid(row=numOrders+4, pady=2, sticky=W)
            self.deleteOrderOptionsEntry = Entry(self, bd=3, width=10)
            self.deleteOrderOptionsEntry.grid(row=numOrders+4, pady=5, column=1)
            global orderToDelete
            orderToDelete = self.deleteOrderOptionsEntry.get()
            self.deleteButton = Button(self, text = "Delete this order", command = self.deleteOrder)
            self.deleteButton.grid(row=numOrders+5, pady=5, column=1)
        def deleteOrder(self):
            conn = sqlite3.connect("testdb.db")
            c = conn.cursor()

            c.execute("DELETE FROM orders WHERE orders_id=:1)", (orderToDelete,))

            conn.commit
            c.close()

root = EditOrdersForm()
root.mainloop()
```

The problem I have is with the WHERE statement, how do I refer to orderToDelete. I have tried converting it to a string and using (?) as the parameter but this didn't work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

THe correct syntax for [parameterized](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) query is:

`c.execute("DELETE FROM orders WHERE orders_id=?)", (orderToDelete,))`

I believe you just need to call commit instead of reference it

`conn.commit()`